# Tkinter Canvas Cover Other Widgets

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create an app with a simple layout that aligns a header, a canvas and a footer vertically.

I came up with the following code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class CanvasView(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.height = self.winfo_reqheight()
        self.width = self.winfo_reqwidth()
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.on_resize)

    def on_resize(self, event):
        self.height = event.height
        self.width = event.width
        self.config(width=self.width, height=self.height)
        # print(f"new size={self.width}x{self.height}")


class Viewer:
    def run(self):
        self.make_main_window()
        self.make_header()
        # self.make_canvas()  # * uncomment to see bug
        self.make_footer()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def make_main_window(self):
        # main window
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title = "My Tk Layout Test"
        root.geometry("640x480")
        root.update()  # force update to set minsize
        root.minsize(root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height())
        self.root = root

    def make_header(self):
        header_frm = ttk.Frame(master=self.root)
        header_frm.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        lbl = tk.Label(header_frm, text="My Viewer Header Text")
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        # config uniform column sizes
        num_col, _ = header_frm.grid_size()
        for i in range(num_col):
            header_frm.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1, uniform="tag")
        self.header_frm = header_frm

    def make_canvas(self):
        canvas_frm = ttk.Frame(master=self.root)
        canvas_frm.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        canvas = CanvasView(canvas_frm, bg="red")
        canvas.pack()
        self.canvas_frm = canvas_frm

    def make_footer(self):
        btn_frm = ttk.Frame(master=self.root)
        btn_frm.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
        btn_list = [
            tk.Label(btn_frm, text=""),  # spacer
            tk.Label(btn_frm, text=""),  # spacer
            tk.Button(btn_frm, text="Control 1"),
            tk.Button(btn_frm, text="Control 2"),
            tk.Button(btn_frm, text="Control 3"),
            tk.Button(btn_frm, text="Control 4"),
            tk.Button(btn_frm, text="Control 5"),
            tk.Label(btn_frm, text=""),  # spacer
            tk.Label(btn_frm, text=""),  # spacer
        ]
        for i, btn in enumerate(btn_list):
            btn.configure(height=2)  # height in text units
            btn.grid(row=0, column=i, sticky="nsew")
        # config uniform column sizes
        num_col, _ = btn_frm.grid_size()
        for i in range(num_col):
            btn_frm.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1, uniform="tag")
        self.footer_frm = btn_frm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    viewer = Viewer()
    viewer.run()
```

Without calling `self.make_canvas()`, I get the following screen which shows the header and footer nicely:

[image]

But when `self.make_canvas()` is called, I get the following:

[image]

How do I fix it so that the red canvas doesn't run over my footer?

Comment: Try calling `make_canvas()` after `make_footer()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canvas isn't *covering* other widgets, it's forcing them out of the window. You are forcing the window to be a specific size, and then you are adding widgets that collectively are too tall to fit so tkinter has to shrink something so it can fit all of the widgets in the window.

The order in which you call `pack` matters. When widgets don't fit, the packer will start to reduce widgets in size to fit, starting with the last widget added to a given space. In this case, the footer is the last widget added so tkinter will shrink it so that it will fit. Eventually, it will shrink to a size of zero.

A simple solution is to add the header and footer before adding the canvas. That way, if the widgets don't fit then the canvas will be the one to shrink. Since it is the largest widget and it is scrollable, this is the logical widget to allow to shrink and therefore should be packed last in chronological order.

From the official documentation, in a section titled [The Packer Algorithm](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/pack.htm#M27):

> If the cavity should become too small to meet the needs of a content then the content will be given whatever space is left in the cavity. **If the cavity shrinks to zero size, then all remaining content on the packing list will be unmapped from the screen** until the container window becomes large enough to hold them again.